# How to parse text over multiple lines with textfsm?

Tags: text-parsing, python-textfsm

I understood that TextFSM is a good way to parse text files, however, I see that it can parse data over single lines, my question is how to parse text spread over multiple lines.

```
    <Page>


CUSIP No. 123456                  13G                   Page 2 of 10 Pages
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     (1)    NAMES OF REPORTING PERSONS

            ABC Ltd.

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     (2)    CHECK THE APPROPRIATE BOX IF A MEMBER OF A GROUP
                                                               (a)  [ ]
                                                               (b)  [X]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     (3)    SEC USE ONLY
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     (4)    CITIZENSHIP OR PLACE OF ORGANIZATION

            Bruny Islands
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NUMBER OF      (5)   SOLE VOTING POWER
                     0
SHARES         -----------------------------------------------------------------

BENEFICIALLY   (6)   SHARED VOTING POWER

1,025,824 shares of Common Stock


OWNED BY       --------------------------------------------------------------

EACH           (7)   SOLE DISPOSITIVE POWER
                     0
REPORTING      --------------------------------------------------------------

PERSON WITH:   (8)   SHARED DISPOSITIVE POWER

1,025,824 shares of Common Stock


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     (9)    AGGREGATE AMOUNT BENEFICIALLY OWNED BY EACH REPORTING PERSON

1,025,824 shares of Common Stock


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     (10)   CHECK BOX IF THE AGGREGATE AMOUNT
            IN ROW (9) EXCLUDES CERTAIN SHARES
                                                                          [ ]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     (11)   PERCENT OF CLASS REPRESENTED
            BY AMOUNT IN ROW (9)
            4.15%
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     (12)   TYPE OF REPORTING PERSON
            CO
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

in the above text, I want to parse Names of reporting persons and Citizenship or place of organization, how which is not in a single line. What is the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with TextFSM state transition.

This template does what you need:

```
Value REPORTING_PERSONS (\S+[\S ]+)
Value CITIZENSHIP (\S+[\S ]+)

Start
  ^.+NAMES OF REPORTING PERSONS -> Person
  ^.+CITIZENSHIP OR PLACE OF ORGANIZATION -> Citizenship
  ^ +NUMBER OF -> Record

Person
  ^ +${REPORTING_PERSONS}
  ^-+ -> Start

Citizenship
  ^ +${CITIZENSHIP}
  ^-+ -> Start
```

Result:

```
REPORTING_PERSONS    CITIZENSHIP
-------------------  -------------
ABC Ltd.             Bruny Islands
```

Here you can see a few examples:
https://github.com/google/textfsm/wiki/Code-Lab

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Comment: Whats the intention of using the " ^ +NUMBER OF -> Record " in this case? Won't it just end it by it self as it won't find any other matches?

Answer (score 0):

```
Value REPORTING_PERSON (\S+[\S ]+)
Value CITIZENSHIP (\S+[\S ]+)

Start
  ^.+NAMES\s+OF\s+REPORTING\s+PERSONS -> Person
  ^.+CITIZENSHIP\s+OR\s+PLACE\s+OF\s+ORGANIZATION -> Citizenship
  ^ NUMBER OF -> Record

Person
  ^(\s+)${REPORTING_PERSON} -> Start

Citizenship
  ^\s+${CITIZENSHIP} -> Start
```

Comment: You can use as by using start in same line.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a long and complicated line that I don't want to come up with a specific regex for.

```
LSBATCH: User input
/hps/nobackup2/production/metagenomics/assembly-pipeline/prod/venv/bin/python /hps/nobackup2/production/metagenomics/...  -p DRP000303  -r DRR000714
```

Instead, I just match the complete line that follows a marker line containing `User input`:

```
# match entire line
Value job_command (.*)

Start
  # match line after line containing "User input"
  ^.*User input -> JobCommand
  # some more rules...

JobCommand
  ^${job_command} -> Start
```